# como puedo hacer que me imprima numero que no son 0

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Como puedo hacer que me  imprima en consola solo  numeros que no son 0

ejemplo 10203 son numeros que ingreso 
 pero quiero que me imprima 123

```
var dato = prompt( "ingrese  5 digitos" )
var arregloDatos = []

for( i = 0; i <= dato; i++ ) {
  var datoUsuario = prompt( "ingrese 5 digitos " + i )
  datoUsuario = arregloDatos.push( )
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Sube tu código por favor. Pero para pista... Usa un `while`

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También a leer [ask], para luego editar tu pregunta y añadir mayor detalle. **No olvides incluir una etiqueta con el lenguaje que utilizas**. Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, no añadas el código en comentarios, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que tienes como parte de ella.

Comment: estoy intentando con js

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo el porque de tu codigo, pero si estas buscando reemplazar los 0  basta con hacer un **[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)** por 0 y luego un **[join()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-join-method/)**:

```js
let dato = prompt("Ingrese un nro");

console.log(dato.split('0').join(''));
```

Comment: muchas gracias perdon creo que no me hize entender en el codigo que puse

Comment: voto por el split-join porque es más eficiente que el replace con expresion regular

Answer (score 2):

Podías usar [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) para eliminar los ceros (`0`)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var input = prompt( "ingrese  5 digitos" );
var output = input.replace(/0/g, '');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método `filter` de los *array*, aplicado a tu cadena:

```js
var test = "023459003";
var result = Array.filter.call( this, test, function( val ) { return val != '0'; } ).join( '' );

console.log( result );
```